# CSS aside height 100% when using sticky footer

Tags: css, cross-browser, sticky-footer

I have a layout with header and [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/). Both are 40px high. Now I need to add aside with a scroolbar, which will fill the free space (verticaly). It should looks like that:

[image: preview]

There are two restrictions:

- no JavaScript
- no CSS3 calc() function

Is there any strict CSS solution of this problem?

Comment: What happens to the right column, how does it scroll?

Comment: It's a content. There is a scrool if there is too much content, but the height don't have to be fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a little demo of what I'm about to explain: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/xnjzd/).

First, position your `header` and `footer` using `absolute` and `fixed`, respectively. Add `40px` of padding to both top and bottom of `body`, and make sure its `box-sizing` is `border-box`. Set your `aside`'s `height` to `100%`, and also make sure it's a `border-box`. Basically;

HTML:

```
<header>
    I'm a header!
</header>
<aside>
    Lots and lots and lots of content!
    Glee is awesome!
</aside>
<footer>
    I'm a footer!
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
footer {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
aside {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; /*make sure there are scrollbars when needed*/
}
```

Comment: Cool! I haven't heard about box-sizing before:). I will test it right now.

Comment: @Abody97 you should reverse the order of your prefixed properties. put the spec property last so when browsers start supporting the spec and not their own prefix (-webkit, etc) you wouldn't need to update your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

With only `position: fixed`, margins (of 42px for testing purpose and because, well, 42 but it should really be 40px) and an extra div inside `#aside`, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/xcuVv/2/ that work in Firefox, Chrome, Safari 4, IE8 and Opera 11 or 12 but fails in IE7 and will need fallback if compatibility is needed.

Beware that this design doesn't take into account:

- vertical space on a netbook or a smartphone
- what happens if header and footer occupy more than 40px (zoom text up to 200% per WCAG 2.0, larger fonts than usual on some OS and browsers, etc)
- internal scroll (into aside) is nearly impossible in some mobile browsers
- people using the space or page down key for scrolling exactly one page will now scroll one and a half screen (80px too much) and that will annoy them (err, us). Please PLEASE allow your bars to be hidden or reduced to a single button and back to a bar by a simple click on a button managed in JS...

Comment: In your demo, if you scroll to the right, the `main` part partially covers the `aside`.

Comment: Right, width in pixels "just for the demo" wasn't sufficient, it needed `width: auto`. Fiddle edited